# SQL Server: Trigger, constraint or function?

Tags: sql-server, function, triggers

I have a table where I want to implement the following:

```
TableA (col1 int,col2 (varchar(10),col3 int default 99)
```

`col3` can have only have numbers from `1` in ascending order.

```
1 A 1
2 A 2
3 A 3
4 A 99
5 A 4
```

for same `col2`, no two values of `col3` can be same. but they can be same for different `col2`

```
1 A 1
2 A 2
3 A 3
4 A 99
5 A 4
6 B 1
6 B 2 
6 b 99
```

So, in this scenario, should I use a trigger, or function or this can be implemented by constraints as well? Please note that for `col3`, `99` is default, other values are manually updated.

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that `col3` values are greater than 1

```
ALTER TABLE TableA
ADD CONSTRAINT gt1 CHECK (col3 >= 1)
```

If the default value `99` can be set once for the same `col2`, simply use a unique constraint

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name
ON TableA(col2, clo3)
```

If the default value can be set more than once, use a filtered Indexes (SQL Server 2008 +)

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX name
ON TableA(col2, clo3)
WHERE col3 <> 99;
```